# What's a current feedback amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Another opamp question. Most opamps seem to be voltage feedback amplifiers (VFA), but there also seem to be current feedback amplifiers (CFA). When would you use a CFA, and what are their (dis/)advantages?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have not yet read  [Voltage feedback vs. current feedback amplifiers:
Advantages and limitations by Xavier Ramus](http://www.ieee.li/pdf/viewgraphs/current_feedback_vs_voltage_feedback_amplifiers.pdf) I would recommend that, it is both nice and in depth on this subject

**Classical Advantages of Voltage Feedback Op Amps**

- Typically can deliver better DC accuracy

  - This is most applicable to pulse oriented signal requirements - typically, DC precision is less important in AC coupled (communications) channels
- Can be the lowest overall equivalent input noise

  - Best noise (< 1.2nV/√Hz) comes at the price of high quiescent current and
    non-unity gain stability.
- Typically internally compensated. Note that some external compensation VFB
  exist.
- The highest accuracy, lower noise devices also have a typical architecture,
  limiting the maximum achievable slew rate.
- Low noise Transimpedance application are ideal target application

**Classical Advantages of Current Feedback Op Amps**

- Essentially unlimited slew rate - gives very high full power bandwidth

  - Most data sheet slew rate numbers are either limited by the input stage buffer or are actually reporting bandwidth limited rise time by mistake
- Nearly gain bandwidth independent

  - Most useful aspect of this is intrinsic low gain stability with very high closed
    loop BW
- Most CFB also provide a large output current drive capability.
- Application such as adder and high gain application are ideal target application

Comment: And yes, I have no answer to your first part of the question - this is only for the second part ;)

Comment: I understand where slew rate comes from in VFA's, but how come that CFA's has 'Essentially unlimited slew rate'?